Detect if string ends with 'A' assembly (HLA) program
Im trying to figure out why my program doesn't output 1 if the string ends with an
A.
For example this is what it outputs
Please enter a string to process
sfrA
----> here is the string you entered: sfrA
Please enter a string to process
gtf
----> here is the string you entered: gtf


Instead it should out put
Please enter a string to process
sfrA
after endsWithA --- result= 1

I don't see a part of my code working in the output and I also get a memory access violation error after I inputted gtf. Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is my current code so far
program StringProgram;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );
#include( "cs17string.hla" ); // allows use of gets and puts

static
  stringData : dword;
  answer : int32;

procedure endsWithA( stringData : dword ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
static
dReturnAddress : dword;
begin endsWithA;
// Preserve registers
push( EAX );
push( EBX );
push( ECX );
push( EDX );

// Get the return address off the stack
pop( dReturnAddress );

// Get stringData off the stack
mov( stringData, EAX );

// Calculate the length of the string
mov( EAX, EBX );
mov( EAX, ECX );

// Check if the string is empty
cmp( ECX, 0 );
je no_end_with_a;

// Get the last character
dec( ECX );
add( EBX, ECX );
mov( [EBX], AL );

// Compare the last character with 'A' and 'a'
cmp( AL, 'A' );
je end_with_a;
cmp( AL, 'a' );
je end_with_a;

no_end_with_a:
mov( 0, EAX );
jmp done;

end_with_a:
mov( 1, EAX );

done:
// Restore the registers used
pop( EDX );
pop( ECX );
pop( EBX );
pop( EAX );

// Push back the return address
push( dReturnAddress );

// Return from function
ret();

end endsWithA;

begin StringProgram;

stdout.put( "Please enter a string to process", nl );

// This code allocates a string of size 80
mov( @size( int8 ), AL );
mov( 80, BL );
inc( BL );
mul( BL );
mov( 0, EBX );
mov( AX, BX );
malloc( EBX );
mov( EAX, stringData );

// Let's try reading a value into the string
mov( stringData, EAX );
push( EAX );
mov( 80, CX );
push( CX );

call gets;

// Print the string
stdout.put( "----> here is the string you entered: " );

mov( stringData, EAX );
push( EAX );
call puts;

stdout.newln();

// Initialize EAX before calling the function
mov( 0, EAX );

// Pass the string parameter to the function
mov( stringData, EAX );
call endsWithA;
mov( EAX, answer );

// Show the results
stdout.put( "after endsWithA --- result=" );
stdout.put( answer );
stdout.newln();

end StringProgram;


There is no reason to remove the return address from the stack. Also that's not even the return address, it's the EDX you have just pushed. And you are putting it back in the wrong place. Calculate the length of the string ... no, you don't calculate anything.

You have to use pop( stringData, EAX ); instead of mov( stringData, EAX ); to get the stringData off the stack. Also, you have to obtain the characters in stringData using [] and index.
For example,
mov(0, CX);
mov(index, EDX); 
myLoop:
mov([EBX+EDX], CL);
cmp(CL, CH);
je Done;
inc(EDX);
jmp myLoop;
Done:

This loop iterates through the characters in the string saved in EBX until it ends (reaches 0, null character).
Hope this helps!
